# Connection refused thrown when instantiating a new chrome driver

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have a selenium project with cucumber on my local Jenkins server.

```
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        try {
            baseUtil.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is how i instantiate my driver. I have the chrome plugin on jenkins as well.

When i try to build, i get this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure.
>
> ....
>
> Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   localhost:4444 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]
>   failed: Connection refused

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: is Chrome is installed and hub is running there in your jenkins server machine.

Comment: I haven't configured any hub? I'm a tad bit lost on what you mean?

Comment: As per your code, you are pointing the script to run on selenium grid which is local to the jenkins server. The following code will search selenium node on the selenium grid.RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability); please refer the URL for more details on selenium grid http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp

Comment: Right, so i haven't configured any Selenium grid, i'l check into that. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running locally try switching to chromedriver

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
try { 
baseUtil.driver = new ChromeDriver(capability));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

the URL in your previous call was set to point to the hub which you aren't using.
you might need to point it at the local driver location such as:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<pathtoyourchromedriver>/chromedriver.exe");
```